# JavaScript: combine two regular expressions to satisfy both?

Tags: javascript, regex

How can multiple regular expressions be combined to satisfy both conditions?

Below, there are 3 strings and 2 regular expressions:

- The first Regex doesn't allow a string to start with a dollar sign.
- The second Regex doesn't allow the string to have periods.

How can these two regular expressions be combined so that strings don't start with a dollar sign and have periods be considered a match?

```js
var good_string = "flkad sdfa$a f fjf";
var bad_string_1 = "$flkadjf";
var bad_string_2 = "flk.adjf";

var does_not_contain_periods = new RegExp('^[^.]*$');
var does_not_start_with_dollar_sign = new RegExp('^(?!\\$)');
var combined_regular_expressions = new RegExp("(" + does_not_contain_periods.source + ")(" + does_not_start_with_dollar_sign.source + ")");

console.log('--- does_not_contain_periods ---')
console.log(good_string.match(does_not_contain_periods));
console.log(bad_string_1.match(does_not_contain_periods));
console.log(bad_string_2.match(does_not_contain_periods));

console.log('--- does_not_start_with_dollar_sign ---')
console.log(good_string.match(does_not_start_with_dollar_sign));
console.log(bad_string_1.match(does_not_start_with_dollar_sign));
console.log(bad_string_2.match(does_not_start_with_dollar_sign));

console.log('--- combined_regular_expressions ---')
console.log(good_string.match(combined_regular_expressions));
console.log(bad_string_1.match(combined_regular_expressions));
console.log(bad_string_2.match(combined_regular_expressions));

console.log('--- desired result ---')
console.log(good_string.match(does_not_contain_periods) !== null && good_string.match(does_not_start_with_dollar_sign) !== null);
console.log(bad_string_1.match(does_not_contain_periods) !== null && bad_string_1.match(does_not_start_with_dollar_sign) !== null);
console.log(bad_string_2.match(does_not_contain_periods) !== null && bad_string_2.match(does_not_start_with_dollar_sign) !== null);
```

Comment: You can’t simply combine two regexes like that. `/(^[^.]*$)(^(?!\$))/` will never match anything. You have to write the third one as its own regex.

Comment: If you put your regexes in an array, then you could use [`.every(regex => regex. match(yourInputString))`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every).

Comment: can this be combined into one regex instead of looping?

Answer (score 0):

RegExps cannot be easily combined that way.

You better just test (matching makes no sense in this case) all of them.

```
function testAll(regexps, ...args) {
  return regexps.every(regexp => regexp.test(...args));
}

var good_string = "flkad sdfa$a f fjf";
var bad_string_1 = "$flkadjf";
var bad_string_2 = "flk.adjf";

console.log(testAll([/^[^.]*$/, /^(?!\$)/], good_string));
console.log(testAll([/^[^.]*$/, /^(?!\$)/], bad_string_1));
console.log(testAll([/^[^.]*$/, /^(?!\$)/], bad_string_2));
```

Comment: this is good, but can it be done without a loop as a single regex?

Answer (score 0):

You can just use one RegX to test for both by using an OR metaChar "|"

```
var regX = /^\$|\./;
```

Comment: this is close, but i want it to be an AND search, and I realize regex doesn't seem to have an operator for that

Comment: Would you not get that affect by passing the string through this regex as a test. 
This will only return the string if it to match either bad string.

`function chechString(str) {
    if(/^\$|\./.test(str) != true){
 return str;
    }
}`

Comment: I don't have control over how the regexp is tested, i can only pass the regexp into the parameters. this get's very close but i'd want the exact opposite of what this is producing